# Select 1 field from a group

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I am having issues trying to get 1 field to return 1 of a group of fields
Example:
This is what I can get (Using an Inner Join between [Job Name] and [Door Style] columns, both sets of data inherently exist in different tables)

```
-[Job Name],  [Door Style]
-Job1           Door Style1
-Job1           Door Style2 
-Job2           Door Style3
-Job2           Door Style4
```

What I would like is,

```
[Job Name],  [Door Style]
Job1           Door Style1 
Job2           Door Style3
```

I have tried multiple different methods to achieve this, my current method is trying to replicate this below because cross apply does not seem to work with what i am using. (SQl in some form of Access? Software is Cabinet Vision)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fcea9655-2db8-4d83-804d-e85250093b18/how-to-have-a-select-query-like-sql-server-cross-apply-query-in-msaccess?forum=accessdev

If i remember correctly (not in front of the computer with the software at the moment, it throws me an error like "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function"

The Table JobS, includes the Inner Join between Job and Doors and produces data like this

```
[Job Name],  [Door Style]
Job1           Door Style1
Job1           Door Style2 
Job2           Door Style3
Job2           Door Style4
```

Any input on alternative methods or what i might be missing below would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
SELECT JobS.[Job Name], JobS.[Door Name]

from JobS as JobS

inner join (

               select JobS1.JobS.[Job Name], max(JobS1.JobS.[Door Name]) as OneDoor

               from JobS as JobS1

               group by JobS1.[Job Name]) as Q1

on Q1.[Job Name] = JobS.[Job Name] and Q1.OneDoor = JobS.[Door Name]
```

Comment: Your subquery is selecting `jobs1.jobs.fieldname` when it should just be selecting `jobs1.fieldname` ...  With that said, doesn't your subquery produce the entire result you need by itself ?

Comment: If this is SQL Server, put SQL Server tag on your question.  SQL is just a language used by many dbms vendors.

Comment: @Eric -- I believe this is for ms access (although mistakenly tagged)...

Comment: Looks to me like you want the Min() door style, unless the data is not literally `Door Style1`. If this is not your data, edit question to show representative data. Agree with @sgeddes.

Comment: @SGeddes, your change did make this work and that's great, thank you. This may or may not be some form of SQL Server, I cant tell. this is done in the software Cabinet Vision, which does use some Access files for its databases.

At this moment that change does make it work, I am not dealing with a ton of information so efficiency of the code is not a problem for me, when I can afford some spare time I will attempt the cleaner shorter methods.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `First` aggregate to select the first value:

```
SELECT JobS.[Job Name], First(JobS.[Door Name])

FROM JobS as JobS

GROUP BY  JobS.[Job Name]
```

Your attempt, however, should just work too if you don't use a subquery at all:

```
SELECT JobS.[Job Name], Max(JobS.[Door Name])

FROM JobS as JobS

GROUP BY  JobS.[Job Name]
```

However, that'd return the highest value according to string ordering.